# int64_t to std::vector<bool> using only `std`

Tags: c++, c++17, std

Suppose that `x` is an `int64_t`. How can I efficiently convert it to a `std::vector<bool>` with 64 elements, one for each bit of `x`, without using other libraries than `std`?

Edit: `std::bitset<64>` is not an option to me, for instance because I need to call `push_back` and `std::find` on it.

Comment: Unrelated: You may find [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) to be a bit more convenient for this job.

Comment: ^ totally use that.  It was built for it and is less difficult than vector bool.

Comment: Thank you, for what i know, `std::bitset` is fixed-size, so I need to use `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: But you said _with 64 elements_.  So it seems you ***do*** know the size.  So `std::bitset` seems apropriate.

Comment: I said 64 elements because an `int64_t` is composed by 64 bits. This is the starting point, I later need to use the created `std::vector<bool>` in other places where it can grow. If you think that creating a `std::bitset<64>` and then converting it to `std::vector<bool>` is more efficient, feel free to answer the question.

Comment: Paxdiablo has your back in that case. There is no direct way to decompose the integer and store it in the `vector<bool>`. You'll have to take it apart yourself (or with a `bitset`. A shame `bitset` doesn't give begin and end iterators because that would make inserting in a `vector` dead easy.) Side note: You should update the question to include the resizability requirement.

Comment: Thank you @user4581301. I clarified the question, hope it will be ok. I tought it was clear that I was looking for a `std::vector<bool>`, cause you can convert an `int64_t` to a `std::bitset<64>` just by using the ctor `bitset(unsigned long long)`

Comment: No worries. I brought up `bitset` because the variable size requirement was not clear and a lot of people don't know it exists. They fall into `vector<bool>`  unaware just how weird `vector<bool>` is and that there's a better option for a fixed-size array of bits.

Comment: Anyway, Paxdiablo's method still holds if you change `makeVec` so that it takes a reference to an existing `vector<bool>` instead of making a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `makeVec` function below will allow you to turn a 64-bit value into a boolean vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

std::vector<bool> makeVec(int64_t x) {
    std::vector<bool> retVal;
    uint64_t mask = 1ULL << 63;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
        retVal.push_back((static_cast<uint64_t>(x) & mask) == 0 ? false : true);
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    return retVal;
}

int main() {
    auto vec = makeVec (42);
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
        std::cout << (vec[i] ? '1' : '0');
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

---

However, you may find it easier to use a `bitset` for this, so your code becomes a simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
    auto vec = std::bitset<64>(42);
    for (int i = 63; i >= 0; --i) {
        std::cout << vec[i];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The one difference you'll note there is the reversal of the bit positions. With a bitset, position zero is the least significant bit, so you have to adjust for that.

---

If you wanted a similar ordering (the zero index being the *least* significant bit) in the vector solution, that would just be a matter of changing a couple of lines:

```
std::vector<bool> makeVec(int64_t x) {
    std::vector<bool> retVal;
    uint64_t mask = 1;                 // This one ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
        retVal.push_back((static_cast<uint64_t>(x) & mask) == 0 ? false : true);
        mask <<= 1;                    // ... and this one.
    }
    return retVal;
}
```